# Error when installing a ruby gem with the command line

Tags: ruby, linux, sass, rubygems

I'm trying to install sass with the gem command, but I get this warning when I run the command:

```
WARNING:  You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.
```

I am unable to use sass after running the command, as the warning said would happen. What do I do to make it so I can run sass or any other gem programs I want to install in the future? My operating system is Antergos Linux.

Comment: Have you considered using RVM, rather than installing gems manually?

Comment: a quick fix may be to run `export PATH=$PATH:/root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin` as it recommends. But using a version manager is a good idea.

Comment: @maxpleaner this worked perfectly. Thanks!